# C++ getline() with boost::iostreams::filtering_istream works strange

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, iostream, boost-iostreams

Please, help me to understand the reasons for the difference in the behavior of the following program.

The program creates a test text file and a chain of boost filters (`filtering_istream`) from one source and one filter. Then it tries to read some lines.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iostreams/device/file_descriptor.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>


class my_filter : public boost::iostreams::input_filter
{
public:
    explicit my_filter(std::ostream& s) : m_out(s)
    {}

    template<typename Source>
    int get(Source& src)
    {
        int c = boost::iostreams::get(src);
        if(c == EOF || c == boost::iostreams::WOULD_BLOCK)
            return c;

        if(c == '\r')
            return boost::iostreams::WOULD_BLOCK;

        if(c == '\n')
        {
            m_out << m_str << std::endl;
            m_str = "";
        }
        else
        {
            m_str += c;
        }
        return c;
    }
private:
    std::ostream& m_out;
    std::string m_str;
};


int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    boost::iostreams::filtering_istream file;
    const std::string fname = "test.txt";

    std::ofstream f(fname, ios::out);
    f << "Hello\r\n";
    f << "11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111\r\n";
    f << "World!\r\n";
    f.close();

    file.push(my_filter(std::cout));
    file.push(boost::iostreams::file_descriptor(fname));

    std::string s;
    while(std::getline(file, s))
    {}
    return 0;
}
```

Online compilation with clang displays the expected result:

[image]

But if I change the string "111...111" (128 ones) to 127 ones (255 and so on), the result differs:

[image]

This behavior seems incorrect to me.

**Note**: the length of "111...111" (**127 ones**) correlates with **default buffer_size** in `boost::iostreams::filtering_istream::push` method...

```
file.push(my_filter(std::cout), default_buf_size=...)
```

You may see and run code here: [code_example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JJvKfVja9zEqudQv)

## Update 1

I find it strange that under some conditions, the return value of `WOULD_BLOCK` allows you to read further, and under other conditions, it considers that the file is finished. But according to documentation:

> **WOULD_BLOCK** - indicates that input is temporarily unavailable

So it doesn’t indicate the end of stream.

Comment: Not sure how it will affect your code, but have you tried writing to your file using binary form (`ios::binary`), rather than text form? Under Windows `std::ofstream`, when operating in text mode, replaces "\n" with "\r\n" already. So, you may have more '\r' characters in your file than you expect. Online compilers usually use linux underneath, where sole '\n' without preceding '\r' is expected as a line end and `std::ofstream` in text mode does not add any additional '\r' to the file.

Answer (score 3):

What are you trying to do with this part?

```
if(c == '\r')
    return boost::iostreams::WOULD_BLOCK;
```

If you're trying to ignore `\r` characters then you should just skip over them and read another character from the source. The Boost docs have an example that shows exactly this:

```
#include <ctype.h>                 // isalpha
#include <cstdio.h>                // EOF
#include <boost/iostreams/categories.hpp> // input_filter_tag
#include <boost/iostreams/operations.hpp> // get, WOULD_BLOCK

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::iostreams;

struct alphabetic_input_filter {
    typedef char              char_type;
    typedef input_filter_tag  category;

    template<typename Source>
    int get(Source& src)
    {
        int c;
        while ( (c = boost::iostreams::get(src)) != EOF &&
                 c != WOULD_BLOCK &&
                !isalpha((unsigned char) c) )
            ;
        return c;
    }
};
```

This removes all non-alphabetic characters from the source (see https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/input_filter.html).

Now as to why exactly you're seeing the behavior above, this is what's basically happening:

- you are returning `WOULD_BLOCK` from `get()` exactly on a buffer boundary, before any characters were set in the current buffer
- this gets called from a `read()` implementation that looks like this (see the two lines with comments towards the end):

```
template<>
struct read_filter_impl<any_tag> {
template<typename T, typename Source>
static std::streamsize read
   (T& t, Source& src, typename char_type_of<T>::type* s, std::streamsize n)
{   // gcc 2.95 needs namespace qualification for char_traits.
    typedef typename char_type_of<T>::type     char_type;
    typedef iostreams::char_traits<char_type>  traits_type;
    for (std::streamsize off = 0; off < n; ++off) {
        typename traits_type::int_type c = t.get(src);
        if (traits_type::is_eof(c))
            return check_eof(off);
        if (traits_type::would_block(c)) // It gets HERE
            return off; // and returns 0
        s[off] = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
    }
    return n;
}
```

(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/iostreams/read.hpp)

- this in turn is called from code like this:

```
// Read from source.
std::streamsize chars =
    obj().read(buf.data() + pback_size_, buf.size() - pback_size_, next_);
if (chars == -1) {
    this->set_true_eof(true);
    chars = 0;
}
setg(eback(), gptr(), buf.data() + pback_size_ + chars);
return chars != 0 ?
    traits_type::to_int_type(*gptr()) :
    traits_type::eof();
```

(https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/boost/iostreams/detail/streambuf/indirect_streambuf.hpp)

So because it hasn't read any characters in the current buffer, it interprets this as end of file and gives up completely.

---

### UPDATE

**(too long for a comment)**

You are not the user of that function, that function is actually the user of your code. Your filter comes between the source and the reader. `WOULD_BLOCK` does indicate that input is temporary unavailable, but it is ultimately the decision of the reader if and when it tries again. The `streambuf` does the best it can in this regard, it processes whatever it managed to get from the source and then tries to read again (that's why it doesn't stop the first time you return `WOULD_BLOCK`, after `Hello`). But if the source doesn't return anything more and the `streambuf` buffer is empty, it basically has no choice but to consider it reached the end of the source. It has no more characters to process in the buffer and can't get more from the source.

You will see the same behavior if you put two consecutive `\r` anywhere. Try this for example:

```
f << "Hello\r\r\n";
f << "nothing\r\n";
f << "World!\r\n";
```

Note the two `\r`s after `Hello`. And this has nothing to do with buffer sizes. It's just a read from the source that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Thanks @lonut! 1) it's legacy =( 2) i've seen examples from boost, but: 3) I don't understand why returning WOULD_BLOCK from filter::get() causes return eof() in reading func?

Comment: `WOULD_BLOCK` stops reading from the source and basically returns whatever it already read in the current iteration. Because this happens exactly on the buffer boundary, it hasn't read anything yet, so it returns `0`. A read that doesn't return any data is interpreted as an end of file. Once the eof flag is set, future reads from the stream will fail, so it stops completely.

Comment: What you wrote is the logic of these functions - it is more or less clear. But don’t you find it strange that under some conditions, the return value of WOULD_BLOCK allows you to read further, and under others, it considers that the file is finished?But “WOULD_BLOCK - indicates that input is temporarily unavailable”: it doesn’t indicate the end of stream. As a user of this function I have no idea about its internal buffer and its bounds...

Comment: @snake_style I added an update to the answer because it was too long for a comment.